# How to create line of text using Core Text in python

Tags: python, macos, core-text

In python, I'm trying to create a line of text using OS X's Core Text, but the Apple guidelines are quite opaque.

From: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/CoreText_Programming/LayoutOperations/LayoutOperations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005533-CH12-SW1

I now have the following code, but this doesn't produce a valid PDF.

```
CGContextBeginPage(writeContext, mediaBox)
CGContextSaveGState(writeContext)
CGContextDrawPDFPage(writeContext, page)
CGContextRestoreGState(writeContext)
# Texty bit start here
string = CFSTR("Hello, World!")
attributes = {'kCTFontAttributeName' : "GillSans", 'kCTFontSizeAttribute' : 72}
attrString = CFAttributedStringCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, string, attributes)
CFRelease(string)
CFRelease(attributes)
line = CTLineCreateWithAttributedString(attrString)
CGContextSetTextPosition(writeContext, 10.0, 10.0)
CTLineDraw(line, writeContext)
CFRelease(line)
#Texty bit ends here
CGContextEndPage(writeContext)
```

Any idea why this doesn't work? Currently, I'm getting "'CTLineCreateWithAttributedString' is not defined"

Or, if no one knows anything about this, can they suggest another method in OS X that might work?

Comment: The following seems to get me close, though I'm sure it's still wrong.
`ctfont = CGContextSetFont(writeContext, "Gill Sans")
  CGContextSetFontSize(writeContext, 24)
  attributes = CFDictionaryCreateMutable(None, 1, kCFTypeDictionaryKeyCallBacks, kCFTypeDictionaryValueCallBacks)
  CFDictionaryAddValue(attributes, kCTFontAttributeName, ctFont)
  string = CFAttributedStringCreate(None, CFSTR("Qwe"), attributes)
  line = CTLineCreateWithAttributedString(string)
  CFRelease(string)
  cCFRelease(attributes)`

I get an error that kCTFontAttributeName is undefined, which is odd.

Comment: Please edit the question instead of commenting with code - that is very hard to read! :^(